# Emulate Nexus 7 with Chrome Browser?

Tags: android-emulator

I am trying to support my webapp on the Nexus 7 using Chrome.

I tried installing the android SDK, and creating a avd like the Nexus 7 with the Google Tools, and after waiting 10 minutes for it to boot up, I found no Chrome, and an emulator that is so slow that it is completely useless.  (I am testing a video app, and this thing cant decode a video in real time)

I have done all my iOS testing with the device simulator, and it works well.

Do I have some setting wrong that is causing problems, or am I just wasting my time?

Comment: Try virtual image of Nexus 7 available description here http://androvm.org/blog/

Answer (score 1):

The emulator might be okay for Android applications, but for web applications, you're probably going to need the real thing.

Even the recent Emulation options in Chrome 32.0.1700.76 m, do not match the same rendering on an actual Nexus 7.